# LocalDB Instance disappears after trying to connect using C# SqlConnect when run as local system user

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express, localdb

We are considering using LocalDB for our application in production. Since our service & webapp is running as LOCAL_SYSTEM service it would make sense running the localdb instance as LOCAL_SYSTEM too.

I have been testing for a while now and I am having multiple issues. Tested on multiple machines, x64 OS only.

SQL Server v12 / 2014 Express LocalDB using x64 installer. v14 / 2017 gives the same result. There is no x86 installer that runs on a x64 OS.

```
C:\Temp>echo %username%
lan

C:\Temp>psexec.exe -s cmd.exe

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.175]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>cd c:\Temp

c:\Temp>echo %username%
TSTWCD03$

c:\Temp>SQLLocalDB create MyInstance
LocalDB instance "MyInstance" created with version 12.0.2000.8.

c:\Temp>SQLLocalDB start MyInstance
LocalDB instance "MyInstance" started.

c:\Temp>sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\MyInstance" -Q "SELECT GETDATE()"

-----------------------
2019-07-05 16:37:00.043

(1 rows affected)
```

So the instance is now clearly running.. Let's try to connect using my x64 C# build app:

```
c:\Temp>ODBCTest_x64
Connect using SQL: Data Source = (localdb)\MyInstance; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 10;
SQLCONN State: Open

c:\Temp>SQLLocalDB info MyInstance
Name:               MyInstance
Version:            12.0.2000.8
Shared name:
Owner:              NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Auto-create:        No
State:              Running
Last start time:    05/07/2019 16:36:36
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#F3826724\tsql\query

c:\Temp>dir "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MyInstance"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BC82-AA93

 Directory of C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MyInstance

05/07/2019  16:36    <DIR>          .
05/07/2019  16:36    <DIR>          ..
05/07/2019  16:36                 0 error.log
05/07/2019  16:36            12.030 error1.log
05/07/2019  16:36                 0 error2.log
05/07/2019  16:36         1.048.576 log.trc
05/07/2019  16:36                 0 log_1.trc
05/07/2019  16:36         4.194.304 master.mdf
05/07/2019  16:36         2.097.152 mastlog.ldf
05/07/2019  16:36         2.293.760 model.mdf
05/07/2019  16:36           524.288 modellog.ldf
05/07/2019  16:36        13.434.880 msdbdata.mdf
05/07/2019  16:36           524.288 msdblog.ldf
05/07/2019  16:36            73.728 system_health_0_132068109699630000.xel
05/07/2019  16:36                 0 system_health_0_132068109978530000.xel
05/07/2019  16:36         2.293.760 tempdb.mdf
05/07/2019  16:36           516.096 templog.ldf
              15 File(s)     27.012.862 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  59.358.416.896 bytes free
```

Connecting using the x64 `SqlConnection` is a success.

But our service runs as a x86 application...

```
c:\Temp>ODBCTest_x86
Connect using SQL: Data Source = (localdb)\MyInstance; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 10;
```

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   at ODBCTest.Program.Main(String[] args)

```
c:\Temp>SQLLocalDB info MyInstance
Printing of LocalDB instance "MyInstance" information failed because of the following error:
LocalDB instance "MyInstance" doesn't exist!

c:\Temp>dir "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MyInstance"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BC82-AA93

 Directory of C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MyInstance

05/07/2019  16:36    <DIR>          .
05/07/2019  16:36    <DIR>          ..
05/07/2019  16:36                 0 error.log
05/07/2019  16:36            12.030 error1.log
05/07/2019  16:36                 0 error2.log
05/07/2019  16:36         1.048.576 log.trc
05/07/2019  16:36                 0 log_1.trc
05/07/2019  16:36         4.194.304 master.mdf
05/07/2019  16:36         2.097.152 mastlog.ldf
05/07/2019  16:36         2.293.760 model.mdf
05/07/2019  16:36           524.288 modellog.ldf
05/07/2019  16:36        13.434.880 msdbdata.mdf
05/07/2019  16:36           524.288 msdblog.ldf
05/07/2019  16:36            73.728 system_health_0_132068109699630000.xel
05/07/2019  16:36                 0 system_health_0_132068109978530000.xel
05/07/2019  16:36         2.293.760 tempdb.mdf
05/07/2019  16:36           516.096 templog.ldf
              15 File(s)     27.012.862 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  59.358.351.360 bytes free
```

**WTF just happened?** An x86 SqlConnection to my x64 SQL LocalDB just killed my instance ...  in an instance!

```
c:\Temp>SQLLocalDB create MyInstance
LocalDB instance "MyInstance" created with version 12.0.2000.8.

c:\Temp>SQLLocalDB start MyInstance
LocalDB instance "MyInstance" started.

c:\Temp>SQLLocalDB info MyInstance
Name:               MyInstance
Version:            12.0.2000.8
Shared name:
Owner:              NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Auto-create:        No
State:              Running
Last start time:    05/07/2019 16:53:13
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#23C9D1D8\tsql\query

c:\Temp>ODBCTest_x64
Connect using SQL: Data Source=np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#23C9D1D8\tsql\query; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=10;
SQLCONN State: Open

c:\Temp>ODBCTest_x86
Connect using SQL: Data Source=np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#23C9D1D8\tsql\query; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=10;
SQLCONN State: Open
```

Connecting using the Instance pipe name DOES work!

The Event Log shows me this error when a LocalDB Instance is running as LOCAL_SYSTEM:

> The "DataDirectory" registry value is missing in the LocalDB instance registry key: {F3917303-37C0-418C-8551-390A6E46EEC3}

It might be working using the pipe name but I would really prefer using the Instance name. Any hints on why this is failing when called using an x86 library?

Comment: Using LocalSystem seems like a bad idea to begin with, and because LocalSystem has no user profile (and several other weird anomalies when it comes to permissions/settings/other things that apply to "real" users) I can imagine there's some edge code in the LocalDB instance maintenance code that falls flat on its face when running as LocalSystem (possibly in combination with the registry virtualization that a 32-bit app would get). I recommend trying this again with a local admin user to see if that avoids the trouble (whether or not you decide on that in the end).

Comment: Incidentally, I really can't stress enough what a bad idea it is to run user code under LocalSystem -- it's slightly worse than running as an administrator, even. When people pick this they often do so because they're either under the impression LocalSystem is LocalService (it's not) or because they think maintaining accounts will be a hassle (it's not, there's [virtual accounts](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/service-accounts) now) or because they think nothing really bad can happen anyway (which is false for anything with a network card).

Comment: Don't do this. Just use SQL Server Express.

Comment: Our app uses system resources that a normal administrator has no access to. That's the main reason why we are still running as system. Also SQL Express has a much larger footprint and takes a while to install. I'll see if I can get it to work using a virtual account.

Comment: I've now created a .NET service that creates & shares our MyInstance localdb instance in 'OnStart' and deletes this instance in OnStop. For the moment this seems to be working. I did need to add this virtual user to the local administrator group to be able to share MyInstance.